# Fey Bloodline and non-arcane spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have a Pathfinder character which is mostly an archer-type Ranger, but multiclassed with a level in sorcerer with the fey bloodline.

One aspect of the fey sorcerer bloodline, is the bloodline arcana "Whenever you cast a spell of the compulsion subschool, increase the spell's DC by +2."

Is it sensible that I interpret this as applying even when casting spells that aren't arcane spells (i.e. ranger spells)? I think so, it's not as if the text says "arcane spells" or such, but I thought it worth asking for second opinions.

(Keeping in theme, I also recently noticed the feat [Fey Spell Versatility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fey-spell-versatility) which could grant them access to some extra spells to use as as ranger spells (including a few options which they wouldn't normally have access to as either ranger or sorcerer). Even if one were to rule that the bloodline arcana didn't affect ranger spells normally, I kind of feel like it would be at least thematically appropriate to apply to ones compulsion subschool ones granted via this feat)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Bloodline Arcana: Whenever you cast a spell of the compulsion subschool, increase the spell's DC by +2.

There is no specification about restricting this bonus to sorcerer spells. It affects all the spells of the compulsion subschool you cast, wherever they come from.

From the [Pathfinder FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9ne8):

> The Bloodline Arcana powers apply to all of the spells cast by characters of that bloodline, not just those cast using the sorcerer's spell slots.
>
> General rule: If a class ability modifies your spellcasting, it applies to your spells from all classes, not just spells from the class that grants the ability. (The exception is if the class ability specifically says it only applies to spells from that class.)